# Minimal Perimeter of Rectangle codility

Tags: java, algorithm

This is the task:

An integer N is given, representing the area of some rectangle.

The area of a rectangle whose sides are of length A and B is A * B, and the perimeter is 2 * (A + B).

The goal is to find the minimal perimeter of any rectangle whose area equals N. The sides of this rectangle should be only integers.

For example, given integer N = 30, rectangles of area 30 are:

```
    (1, 30), with a perimeter of 62,
    (2, 15), with a perimeter of 34,
    (3, 10), with a perimeter of 26,
    (5, 6), with a perimeter of 22.
```

Write a function:

```
int solution(int N);
```

that, given an integer N, returns the minimal perimeter of any rectangle whose area is exactly equal to N.

For example, given an integer N = 30, the function should return 22, as explained above.

Assume that:

```
    N is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(sqrt(N));
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).
```

It is my solution to codility task `MInPerimeterRectangle`. It works properly but if we have a test case: " 982451653 " the compiler get an `TIMEOUT ERROR`. It's because the minimal perimeter of this rectangle is created by sides A = 1 and B = 982451653.

So i have a question. Is it a possibility to make **this** solution faster?

```
class Solution {
        public int solution(int N) {
            
            int A = 0;
            int B = N;
            int perimeter = 0;
            for (A = 1; A <= B; A++) {
                if (A * B == N){
                    perimeter = 2 * (A + B);
                    System.out.println("perimeter: " + perimeter);
                }
                if (N % (A+1) == 0) 
                    B = N/(A+1);
            }
            System.out.println("A: " + A);
            
            return perimeter;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Your getting very close to the maximum range of an int in this instance. I'm not entirely sure what it is your trying to achieve. Do you have a link to the original specification?

Comment: How is anyone here supposed to know what is wrong with your code if you do not provide the problem you are solving?

Comment: You're right. I edited my post.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for the code review community

Answer (score 6):

Let l1 and l2 be the length of the sides. Concider that minimizing `|l1-l2|` will minimize the perimeter. So this would be a solution:

```
public int solution(int n) {
    int sumMin =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=1 ;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++) {
        if(n%i==0 ) {
            if(2*(i+n/i) < sumMin) sumMin=2*(i+n/i);    
        }   
    }   
    return sumMin;
}
```

Comment: This is correct solution of course, but i would like to know whether is it a possibility to make **my solution** faster.

Comment: Is this not MAKING it faster by **editing** you code until it looks like this? :P

Comment: You could scan the other way and just return the first divisor encountered.

Comment: what about going not every, but the other one? You just need to calculate sqrt once, then just iterate the other one and check for modular zero. Of course dont forget to check if number is even and you got odd floored sqrt, then decrease by 1. Solved

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you mean by making **this** solution faster.  Anything that changes it will make it no longer **this** solution.

Your fundamental problem is that you’re overflowing.  Use `long` instead.

Your next problem is that you’re looking through way too many `A` values.  Your loop won’t exit until it find the first factor of `N` that is greater than `sqrt(N)`.  But if `N` is prime, this means that your algorithm is `O(N)`.  I would recommend rethinking your approach.  Calculus tells us that the minimum perimeter is with a square, so this means that you want the factor of `N` that is closest to `sqrt(N)`.  So you want to find an efficient way to generate factors of `N`, and go from there.

Comment: Aren't you taking things a bit too literal? Of course he doesn't mean "this solution". Although getting yourself a faster computer will make "this solution" faster.