# How to get the optimal matrix size for a list knowing the length of the list?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have some list with dynamic size. I need to find the optimal matrix size for 2d representation of the list, I don't know how to explain it more precisely, here is an example:

```
> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3]
> somefunc(a)
width: 3 height: 3
```

or

```
> a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
> somefunc(a)
width: 4 height: 3
```

The code I was able to write:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
cols, rows = [],[]
for id in range(1, len(a)):
    if id * (abs(id-len(a))) >= len(a):
        cols.append(id)
        rows.append(abs(id-len(a)))
x,y,z=[],[], []
for col in cols:
    for row in rows:
        if row*col >= len(a):
            x.append(col)
            y.append(row)
            z.append(abs(col-row))
index = z.index(min(z))
print(f'width: {x[index]}', f'height: {y[index]}')

> width: 4 height: 4
```

In some cases, my code works the way I want it to....

I've done everything I can, but I feel like I'm moving in the wrong direction.
I apologize in advance for any mistakes in writing the question, this is my first time.....

Comment: What makes a dimension "optimal"? That seems like quite an arbitrary choice, and your examples don't even fill out the 2D list.

Comment: err, mistake in second example. sorry. My code gives a 9x9 response when the list is 65 elements long, but it would be more logical to get 8x9.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Let me clarify: I don't need to get the filled list, just its length/width. the most important thing is that the area can fully accommodate the list.
i.e. a list with 64 elements should fit into an 8x8 matrix, and a list with 65 elements into an 8x9 matrix.

Comment: okay, so why is `[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3]` 3x3, instead of 2x4 or 4x2 (both of which are smaller)? And why is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]` 4x3 instead of 3x4? (do the actual _value arrangements_ matter?) I.e. "make all your rules explicit, don't make people guess at what you want".

Comment: @mike-pomax-kamermans All right, I'll try
First of all, it doesn't matter if the last row is filled in completely or not, because in the future the gaps will be implicitly filled in (the original list won't change because it doesn't matter), what matters is the width, i.e. a list of 65 elements is 8x9 not 9x8.
More examples: a list of 5 elements is 2x3, a list of 101 elements is 10x11.

Comment: okay, so why is your list of 7 elements 3x3 instead of 4x2? because 3x3 is 9 elements with 2 empty, whereas 4x2 is 8 elements with only 1 empty. What's the rule there? And quite importantly, please address that [in your post](/help/how-to-ask) (people should see that explanation in the post itself rather than having to read through the comment thread)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to have a 2d array basically that has each different number in a row with itself:

```
[
[0,0,0,0]
[1,1,1]
[2,2,2,2,2]
..
]
```

Here is some code that can do that:

```
lst = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]

lst_2 = []


for x in lst:
    found = False
    for y in lst_2:
        if len(y) > 0 and y[0]==x:
            y.append(x)
            found = True
    
    if not found:
        lst_2.append([x])


print(lst_2)

width = max([len(i) for i in lst_2])
height = len(lst_2)

print(f'width: {width}', f'height: {height}')
```

Comment: Different number can only be in the last line, i.e. 
[[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1]]

Comment: @minto I am not following then, are you saying the value of the numbers don't matter? Or do you want it to be ordered numerically for some reason?

Comment: In real work, the list consists of ordered tuplets, I have a function that displays the items on a line of a certain width, the height depends on the number of items in the list, if they are missing, the void is filled with (255,255,255)
For example, if my list contains 63 elements, and I output it with a width of 8 elements, the last line will look like this: (...),(...),(255,255,255), the other 7 will be filled with information.

Comment: So you want to take in the width and create basically a 2d array that fits this list into it, filling in the missing information at the end? You could achieve something like this by taking the length of the initial array and dividing by the width to get the height, then appending:
 `for x in range(width*height % len(arr)):
     lst.append((255,255,255))`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a matrix A with **optimal size** defined as the matrix A with dimensions `w` and `h` such that `max(w,h)` is **minimized** such that A can hold all the elements. This is equivalent to determining the smallest possible perimeter to store `n` elements, where we let `n` be the length of your input list.

See this solution for an elegant way to solve this problem:
[Minimal Perimeter of Rectangle codility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621014/minimal-perimeter-of-rectangle-codility)

This solution has time complexity `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what I need. I'll try to include it in my main code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to my problem. This code works, I haven't done enough tests, but so far there have been no errors.

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

#a = [1,1,1] # > (2,2)
#a = [1,1,1,1] # > (2,2)
#a = [1,1,1,1,1] # > (2,3)
#a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] # > (3,3)
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] # > (3,4)
max_h = ceil(sqrt(len(a)))
size = (5,5)
for x in range(1, max_h+1):
    if x*max_h >= len(a):
        size = (x, max_h)
        break
print(size)
assert(size[0]*size[1] >= len(a))
```

Comment: I wrapped this code in a function and tested it in a loop for 100000 iterations, no errors.